# Determinant calculation javascript

Tags: javascript, matrix

I have got a bit of a javascript and html code and I want to display a calculated value of a matrix determinant, but the function doesn't want to display it in a input place,where I want it to be displayed, instead i get a blank space.
**HTML**

```
<div id = "table">
<div id = "header">Wyznacznik [3x3]</div>
 <form id = "row1">
    <input type = "text" class = "det"/><!--first row-->
    <input type = "text" class = "det"/>
    <input type = "text" class = "det"/>
 </form>
 <form id = "row2">
    <input type = "text" class = "det"/><!--second row-->
    <input type = "text" class = "det"/>
    <input type = "text" class = "det"/>
</form>
<form id = "row3">
    <input type = "text" class = "det"/><!--third row-->
    <input type = "text" class = "det"/>
    <input type = "text" class = "det"/>
</form>
<div class = "count" onclick="det(3)"><a href = "#">Wylicz</a></div>
<input type = "text" id = "calcValue"/>
</div>
```

**javascript**

```
function det(size){
var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('det1');
var determinant = 0;
if(size == 2){
determinant = (arr[0].value*arr[3].value) - (arr[1].value*arr[2].value);
document.getElementById('calcValue1').value = determinant;
}
else if(size == 3){
determinant = (arr[0].value*((arr[4].value*arr[8].value) - (arr[5].value *   arr[7].value))) - 
(arr[1].value*((arr[3].value*arr[8].value) - (arr[5].value * arr[6].value))) +
(arr[2].value*((arr[3].value*arr[7].value) - (arr[4].value * arr[6].value))); 
document.getElementById('calcValue').value = determinant;
}
return determinant;
}
```

Comment: Also you shouldn't have spaces around the = in HTML. I don't know how browsers cope with that, but they might see it as a Boolean attribute followed by 2 illegal attributes.

Answer (score 0):

You're getting no elements, try this:

```
var arr = document.getElementsByClassName('det');
```